# Setting up cloud9 on existing EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloud9

I have an existing EC2 `t2.micro` instance. I am able to connect to it from my local machine. Now I want to setup Cloud9 on it but i am having issues. Here are the steps that I have followed but getting error

- I logged into `https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloud9`
- I clicked on *Create new Environment*
- I selected *Connect and run in remote server (SSH)*
- In User, I have tried with both `ec2-user` and `root`
- In the url, I have tried copying the url which i normally use to connect from my localhost. The url is `ec2-user@ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com`
- I copied the **ssh** file from the website into **ec2** hosts location `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on new line

`[ec2-user@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx ~]$ wc -l ~/.ssh/authorized_keys 
2 /home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys`

And whenever i click on next, I get an error that the Cl9 wasn't able to connect with `<username>@<ip_address>`

Comment: Which `AMI` did you choose for your EC2 instance? 

I'm assuming you removed the user from the Host name?

Can you give the exact error message you get? 

Additionally ensure that you have the correct VPC configurations that your EC2 instance lives in. Check the documentation for the correct inbound and outbound rules on your security group: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/ip-ranges.html